# Convert dict to yaml with preserved quotes only for values

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have python dict:

```
t1 = [{'system': 'android',
           'nice': False,
           'pass': [{'success': ['a', 'b', 'c']}],
           'warning': [{'pass': ['a', 'b', 'c']}],
           'number': 1}]
```

I need to get YAML like this, where only values are in quotes:

```
- system: 'android'
  nice: false
  pass:
    - success:
        - 'a'
        - 'b'
        - 'c'
  warning:
    - pass:
        - 'a'
        - 'b'
        - 'c'
  number: 1
```

What I tried:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(t1, buf)
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(buf.getvalue())
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

but yaml.preserve_quotes = True does not work and output is:

```
  - system: android
    nice: false
    pass:
      - success:
          - a
          - b
          - c
    warning:
      - pass:
          - a
          - b
          - c
    number: 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: I re-indented your expected output as it was not valid YAML.

Comment: @Anthon what exactly is wrong with my expected YAML? :)

Comment: When you click on the 'edited ... ago' link above my name you can see what I changed. The `n` of `nice` has to be in the same column as the `s` of `system`, and similar for `pass`, `warning` and `number`

Answer (score 1):

The "preserve" in `preserve_quotes` is to **keep existing quotes** when loading and
then dumping using `ruamel.yaml`. Since what you load has not quotes, setting it has no function.

But you can load your expected output and analyse how that is loaded,
which gives a clue about what to do:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- system: 'android'
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(type(data[0]['system']))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString'>
- system: 'android'
```

so the thing to do is:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString as SQ

t1 = [{'system': SQ('android'),
           'nice': False,
           'pass': [{'success': [SQ('a'), SQ('b'), SQ('c')]}],
           'warning': [{'pass': [SQ('a'), SQ('b'), SQ('c')]}],
           'number': 1}]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)

def dedent(s):
    res = []
    count = 0
    for line in s.splitlines(True):
        if not res:
            while line[count] == ' ':
                count += 1
        res.append(line[count:])
    return ''.join(res)

yaml.dump(t1, sys.stdout, transform=dedent)
```

which gives what you want:

```
- system: 'android'
  nice: false
  pass:
    - success:
        - 'a'
        - 'b'
        - 'c'
  warning:
    - pass:
        - 'a'
        - 'b'
        - 'c'
  number: 1
```

However if you read this with a proper YAML parser the quotes are superfluous.

All of your indents in ruamel.yaml are the same, since you seem to want to have an offset
for the sequence element indicator (`-`), you need to increase the sequence indent from
the normal `2` to e.g. `4`. But since your root collection is a sequence, this
gets of course indented as well. That is why you need to post-process the output
(using `transform=dedent`) to get the root level
sequence element indicator flush with the left margin.